# angular js data table pass row data into fucntion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I am using angular js data table to my project. currently i am trying to pass value to my onclick function . Please check my below code

```
$scope.loadRequestApproval = function () {

        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withOption('ajax', {
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: appConfig.apiUrl + "/finalizedAllList?reqTraceId=" + $scope.requestApprovalId,
                xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
                type: 'POST',
                data: function (d) {
                    return JSON.stringify(d);

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    ajaxErrorHandler.handle(response);
                }
            })

            .withDataProp('data')
            .withOption('processing', true)
            .withOption('serverSide', true)
            .withOption('scrollY', '400px')
            .withOption('scrollX', '100%')
            .withOption('scrollCollapse', true)

            .withOption('drawCallback', function (settings) {

            });
        $scope.dtOptions.withOption('fnRowCallback',
            function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                $compile(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull)($scope);
            });
        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('treaceId.traceId').withTitle('Trace ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('Name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('matchRatio').withTitle('Match Strength %'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('resultId').withTitle('Action').renderWith(function (data, type, full) {
                 
                full.resultId= '500asdx';

                return '<div class="btn-group-xs">' +
                    '  <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-xs btn-success" ng-click="loadDataById(' + full.resultId+ ');">' +
                    '    <i class="ion ion-eye"></i>' +
                    '  </button>' +
                    '</div>';
            }).withClass('text-center').notSortable()
        ];

    };
```

I am trying to pass my resultId to my loadDataById function. But its not worked.

my function is as below

```
   $scope.loadDataById = function (requestID) {
            console.log(requestID)
        };
```

I found some points regarding my issue. When i use numbers, console log is printed. but if its string, console log did not print.
Ex:

```
full.resultId= 500;
    console log print correctly as 500

full.resultId= '500asdx';
console log did not print.
```

why i can not use string to do this. I think you can get the my problem. thanks

Comment: Hi Kumara, I think the simple answer I believe is that in the return code where you have the loadDataById function in the ng-click event, it would output to the DOM as  `ng-click="loadDataById(500)"` for number and `ng-click="loadDataById(500asdx)"`. It is the lack of inverted comma for the string that is probably the reason.

Comment: how i modify my code , can u help me

Comment: If strings are more important then just do `ng-click="loadDataById(\'' + full.resultId + '\');"` or alternatively `ng-click="loadDataById(' + "'" + full.resultId + "'" + ');"`
I would say go for the first one as it is cleaner

Comment: working well. thank you very much,, I can sleep now :D

Comment: No worries happy to help. Just gonna put the same thing as the answer to the question. It would help if you can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the only thing missing are the inverted commas for strings in the ng-click function. Solution:

`ng-click="loadDataById(\'' + full.resultId + '\');"`

OR

`ng-click="loadDataById(' + "'" + full.resultId + "'" + ');"`

I would say go for the first one as it is cleaner